# No Poster Image for Flash Fallback

Tags: flash, video.js, poster

I see a number of questions asking how to set a poster image for the "VideoJS" flash player fallback without a solution. I thought I'd just ask the same question.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it occoured because I wanted my Player to be responsive. Therefore I had to set the heigth and width of the videoplayer auto and ajust the css as follows [here](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/videodrome/videojs/).

HTML:

```
<video id="myVideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
                           controls preload="auto" width="auto" height="auto"
                           poster="img/myVideoPoster"
                           data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
                        <source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
                        <source ... />
</video>
```

CSS:

```
.video-js {
    padding-top: 56.26% !important;
}

.vjs-fullscreen {
    padding-top: 0px !important;
}
```

This worked out well except the flashplayer, which didn't show the poster image.
To solve this problem I had to add the following rules to the css to ajust the poster image.

```
.vjs-poster {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I hope it will help you too.

Answer (score 1):

You can just specify the poster attribute in the HTML5 video tag and Video.js will take care of it, regardless of the tech used for playback.

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" poster="http://videojs.com/img/poster.jpg" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268" data-setup='{}'>
  <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
  <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type='video/webm'>
</video>
```

If you're wondering, what Video.js does is create a div with a class of `vjs-poster` and sets the background to whatever was specified in the poster attribute. You can view an example of this in action in this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/UXOvOru/1). The player options are set to load the Flash player first regardless of whether or not the browser can play the file natively.

Answer (score 0):

We've had no luck getting video.js to pull the poster directly from the video node. Additionally we pass the `poster` directly to the constructor as an option.

```
var videoPlayer = _V_('snippet-video', {
  autoplay: false,
  controls: true,
  preload:  'auto',
  height:   450,
  width:    420,
  poster:   'some/preview/url'
})
```

That works for the Flash fallback and the native video element.